# Windows XP Mode with Dual Monitors - Applications Not Appearing Correctly

Tags: windows-7, multiple-monitors, virtualization, windows-xp-mode

We have machines with Windows 7 installed and dual monitors. When we run a virtual application using XP Mode, any dialogue windows in the application appear centered between the two monitors. If we drap them over to one side, the location is not "remembered" like it is with other applications.

Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: Does it work correctly with other apps in XP mode?

Comment: Nope. All applications. So Microsoft Office, custom VB6/C++ apps, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if it will work but have you tried UltraMon?

http://www.realtimesoft.com/ultramon/download.asp

Comment: We may try this if we can't figure it out.

Comment: @JasonN.Gaylord - Can you explain how you used this to solve the problem?

Comment: We didn't figure it out. We actually scrapped the idea and worked on upgrading the application.

Comment: @JasonN.Gaylord -Oh.  That's too bad.  I thought because it was marked as an answer... oh well.

Answer (score 2):

**[Actual Window Manager](http://www.actualtools.com/windowmanager/)** is the best window manager with multi-monitor support (by a country mile) i have yet seen, and i have tried a lot.

*Actual Window Manager is shareware, try before you buy (60 days evaluation period).*