# Using Windows 7 XP Mode

Tags: windows-7, multiple-monitors, windows-xp-mode

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Windows XP Mode with Dual Monitors - Applications Not Appearing Correctly](https://superuser.com/questions/80461/windows-xp-mode-with-dual-monitors-applications-not-appearing-correctly)

We have a Windows 7 machine, setup using dual monitors.  We have a few programs that won’t work with Windows 7 but work fine using XP Mode.  However, the problem is with the dual monitors.  If the program running using XP mode displays a dialog box, it always centers it between the two monitors.  Half of the dialog box is on one screen and half is on the other.  We then have to move the box over to one of the monitors to read what it says.  It does this with any program running XP mode and is quite annoying.

Comment: Hmm, I don't see a question anywhere in here... ;)

Answer (score 1):

My solution isn't really a solution, but when I run XP Mode I run it as XP's desktop maximized on my second monitor. That way all the XP programs run on the XP desktop (not using the integration), and I work that way.

Probably not what you're looking for, but it solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try running it in the XP Virtual Machine and maximize it in the second screen. Also, try changing display settings in the XP virtual machine as that may be the cause of your problem.